# Unable to upgrade Perl 5.8 to 5.16 in RHEL 7.6

Tags: linux, bash, perl, rhel, rhel7

6 and am unable to upgrade my machine from 5.8.9. When I install using yum install perl, it says successfully installed, but when I check version it is still the old one. I need the version to be 5.10 or above. Following are the details:

```
bash$ cat /etc/*release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
bash$ 
bash$ yum info perl
Name        : perl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 4
Version     : 5.16.3
Release     : 294.el7_6
Size        : 22 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhel-7-server-rpms
Summary     : Practical Extraction and Report Language
URL         : http://www.perl.org/
bash$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.9 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2008, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.
bash$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/a
bash$ whereis perl
perl: /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl5.6 /usr/local/bin/perl5.8 /usr/local/bin/perl /auto/usrcisco-linux-rhel7.0-x86-64/packages/perl/perl-5.8.9/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz
```

**Solution:**

```
bash$ whereis perl5.16.3
perl5.16: /usr/bin/perl5.16.3
bash$ ll | grep -i perl
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   19 Jul  2  2019 perl -> /usr/ravi/bin/perl
bash$ sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/perl5.16.3 perl
bash$ 
bash$ ll | grep -i perl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   19 Feb 22 17:49 perl -> /usr/bin/perl5.16.3
bash$ perl --version
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 39 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall
```

**Thanks in Advance for any input**

Comment: Check you PATH environmental variable.

Comment: Updated my PATH in question itself. I thought /usr/bin would be enough for it. But apparently that is not the case

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is the first Perl in your PATH

Comment: Solved it by changing the sym link of perl.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash$ whereis perl5.16.3
perl5.16: /usr/bin/perl5.16.3
bash$ ll | grep -i perl
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   19 Jul  2  2019 perl -> /usr/ravi/bin/perl
bash$ sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/perl5.16.3 /usr/bin/perl
bash$ 
bash$ ll | grep -i perl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   19 Feb 22 17:49 perl -> /usr/bin/perl5.16.3
bash$ perl --version
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 39 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall
```

Comment: It's not clear which symlink you changed. (Sure, it's named `perl`, but in which directory.) It could be very dangerous to a change symlink to `perl` used by the system.